# Cordova Javascript SQLite Order By DateTime

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, cordova

How to select and order with datetime?

My query:

`SELECT id, title, note, lastUpdated, dateCreated FROM notes ORDER BY datetime(lastUpdated) DESC`

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    title TEXT NOT NULL, 
    note TEXT, 
    lastUpdated DATETIME,
    dateCreated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`
```

My insertion:

```
INSERT INTO notes (
    title, note, lastUpdated) 
VALUES (?1,?2,?3)`, [$scope.note.title, $scope.note.note, new Date()]
```

I insert the date with javascript `new Date()`.

If I print the result from this select query:

`SELECT id, title, note, lastUpdated, dateCreated FROM notes ORDER BY datetime(lastUpdated) DESC`

the result looks something like this:

```
dateCreated:'2021-01-17 09:24:13'
id:1
lastUpdated:'Mon Jan 18 2021 00:37:36 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)'
note:'Test'
title:'Title'
```

Comment: The format of the column lastUpdated is not comparable. Change it to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

Comment: Yes, I have to change the insert into `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO notes (
    title, note, lastUpdated) 
VALUES (?1,?2,?3)`, [$scope.note.title, $scope.note.note, new Date().toISOString()]
```